# Scala Quasiquote Lifting

Tags: scala, scala-quasiquotes

The Scala documentation for Quasiquotes mentions this when explaining [Lifting](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/lifting.html):

> One can also combine lifting and unquote splicing:

```
 scala> val ints = List(1, 2, 3)
 scala> val f123 = q"f(..$ints)"
 f123: universe.Tree = f(1, 2, 3)

 scala> val intss = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5), List(6))
 scala> val f123456 = q"f(...$intss)"
 f123456: universe.Tree = f(1, 2, 3)(4, 5)(6)
```

Where specifically is the implementation of lifting vs unquote splicing in the code example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are happening at the same time in both examples.

*Unquoting* is the process of substituting a `Tree` somewhere into the structure of another `Tree` (like interpolating). In this example, `ints` isn't exactly a `Tree`, but there exists a `Liftable[List[T]]` that allows us to unquote a `List[T]` into a `Tree`, as if it were a `Tree` (ie. the `Liftable` tells the compiler how to transform the literal `List[Int]` here into a `Tree` so that it may be substituted).

To quote the documentation:

> Unquote *splicing* is a way to unquote a variable number of elements.

Here, the variable number of elements would be the elements in the `List` we want to unquote. If we did `q"f($ints)"`, then we would simply be unquoting `ints` as a single argument of `f`. But perhaps we want to apply repeated parameters to `f` instead. For that we use *unquote splicing*.

```
q"f(..$ints) // Using `..` means we get f(1, 2, 3) instead of f(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Again, the documentation says it best, really:

> Dots near unquotee annotate degree of flattening and are also called splicing rank. `..$` expects argument to be an `Iterable[Tree]` and `...$` expects `Iterable[Iterable[Tree]]`.

So *lifting* allows us to unquote a `List[T]` into the tree `f(x)` as if it were an `Iterable[Tree]`, and *unquote splicing* allows us to unquote the variable number of elements the `List[T]` contained as multiple arguments for `f`.

---

Here are the different relevant combinations:

```
val listTree = q"scala.collection.immutable.List(1, 2, 3)"
val treeList = List(q"1", q"2", q"3")
val literalList = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> q"f($listTree)" // plain unquoting from another Tree
res6: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = f(scala.collection.immutable.List(1, 2, 3))

scala> q"f($literalList)" // unquoting from lifting
res7: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = f(scala.collection.immutable.List(1, 2, 3))

scala> q"f(..$treeList)" // plain unquote splicing
res8: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = f(1, 2, 3)

scala> q"f(..$literalList)" // unquote splicing and lifting
res9: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = f(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: thanks, but i just want to say how stupid it is to name something that is ostensibly a mechanism for substitution with the prefix un-.

Comment: It's not really stupid. Symbols are resolved to what they refer, if `val x = 5` then later `x` will be `5`. Quoting gives a symbol, `'x` is the symbol `x` itself. Later you can *unqoute* `'x` and place it into code where it will refer to something in that context.